# What's the recommended way to manage a toggle state in svelte passed by prop?

Tags: svelte

I am creating a toggle component in Svelte, and I am directly modifying the prop `isActive` in the child component:
https://svelte.dev/repl/da651280c99c471d82944985339f8551?version=3.12.1

I am thinking of the following alternatives:

1. dispatching an event to let the parent modify the state
2. creating a variable that would be initialized from the prop passed by parent

I would like to avoid #1 as it feels overkill.
With #2, where is the best place to initialize a variable based on the prop?

Or what other alternatives would be recommended to manage this case (I have the same issue for other props like passing search text, or list of tags)?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, do you simply want the parent to somehow track the status of `isActive` as well ? In that case you can define a variable in Parent and use `bind:isActive={toggleStatus}` to introduce two-way binding.

Comment: Is it ok to have the child modify the prop? Or should it be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Svelte, two-way binding is encouraged, and updating props directly is usually the way to go. If there are complex actions that should happen when something is updated, perhaps emitting an event is better. In this case, you are already updating the prop, so I would just bind the value like so:

```html
<script>
    import Toggle from './Toggle.svelte';

    let someToggleValue = false;
</script>

<Toggle title="Toggle Header" bind:isActive={someToggleValue}>
     <div class="content">
        The Content
     </div>
</Toggle>
```